# Rails[PaperTrail]: accepts_nested_attributes_for not restored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem. I have three models `faq`, `subgroup`, and `group`. `group` has a one-to-many relationship with `subgroup`, and `subgroup` had a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship. PaperTrail doesn't support HABTM so I changed it to has-many-through. Now when I destroy a `faq` it is reverted with the correct `subgroup` associations.

`group` on the other hand `accepts_nested_attributes_for :subgroups` and it seems to be why it fails. `subgroup` gets destroyed whenever its parent `group` gets destroyed; but PaperTrail won't restore the `subgroup` when the parent `group` is restored. However, I can see that there is versions for `subgroup`, PaperTrail isn't getting called to restore them. How can I do so?

group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subgroups, :dependent => :destroy, inverse_of: :group
    validates :name, presence: true
    #validates :subgroups, length: { minimum: 1 }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subgroups, :allow_destroy => true
    has_paper_trail
end
```

subgroup.rb

```
class Subgroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group, inverse_of: :subgroups
    has_many :faqs_subgroups
    has_many :faqs, through: :faqs_subgroups
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates_presence_of :group
    has_paper_trail
end
```

versions_controller.rb

```
class VersionsController < ApplicationController
    def revert
        @version = PaperTrail::Version.where(:id => params[:id], :item_type => params[:item_type], :item_id => params[:item_id])[0]

        if params[:item_type] == "Group"
            if @version.reify(:has_many => true)
                @version.reify(:has_many => true).save!
            else 
                @version.item.destroy
            end
        else
            if @version.reify
                @version.reify.save!
            else
                @version.item.destroy
            end
        end

        link_name = params[:act] == "undo" ? "redo" : "undo"
        link = view_context.link_to(link_name, revert_version_path(@version.next, :item_type => params[:item_type], :item_id => params[:item_id], :act => "redo"), :method => :post)

        if @version.event == "create" && params[:item_type] == "Faq"
            redirect_to faqs_path, :notice => "Successfully undid #{@version.event}. #{link}"
        elsif @version.event == "create" && params[:item_type] == "Group"
            redirect_to groups_path,  :notice => "Successfully undid #{@version.event}. #{link}"
        else
            redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully undid #{@version.event}. #{link}"
        end
    end
end
```

undo_link method in groups_controller.rb

```
def undo_link
  view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@group.versions.last, :item_type => "Group", :item_id => @group.id, :act => "undo"), :method => :post)
end
```

If PaperTrail does not support reverting `subgroup`, I was thinking about saving the ids and version ids of all the subgroups a `group` has, and perhaps calling PaperTrail to restore those when the parent `group` is restored. What's a plausible way of doing this?

Thanks!

**Edit** forgot to add that I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351572/paper-trail-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for) but I do not have a problem destroying, just restoring.

Comment: As a simple "sanity check" are you sure `@version.reify(:has_many => true)` is populating the `subgroups` association before you call `save!`?

Comment: I would assume so, as that's what they said `:has_many => true` parameter is for. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

**Current Solution:**
Before destroying a group, I save the ids of its subgroups. Then, I pass that array to `revert_version_path`. After `reify.save!` on the group, I call `revert-hm` method in the `versions_controller` to manually `reify.save` the subgroups.

revert_hm in versions_controller.rb

```
def revert_hm(item_type, item_id)
    @version = PaperTrail::Version.where(:item_type => item_type, :item_id => item_id).last
    if @version.reify != nil
        @version.reify.save!
    else
        @version.item.destroy
    end
end
```

I don't save the version ID of the subgroups because they have not been destroyed yet, in which the destroyed version would actually be the latest version you would want to `reify.save`. This can also be used for `:tag_list` of `acts_taggable_on` though warning I cannot get PaperTrail to make new versions when associations or tags are changed.

It's a messy solution so if someone has a better one please say so.

p.s. if you are using elasticsearch you will have to call `Model.import` on your model after calling this method. Otherwise, elasticsearch will think that your model doesn't have these associations.